# How to Providing Drawable for Repository in MVVM, Clean Architecture

Tags: android, mvvm, solid-principles, clean-architecture

i am trying to code with SOLID, and MVVM architecture. But i am confused how to provide drawable to Repository in MVVM

```
interface IStringProvider {
   val mengenaliPotensiDiri: String
   val eventSpesial: String
   val pentingMengenaliDiri: String
   val mengenaliAspekDiri: String
   val mulaiRencanaKarier: String
}

class AssessmentListRepository(private val stringProvider: IStringProvider) {
   fun getAssessmentTopicMengenaliDiri(): List<AssessmentProgressItem> {
      return listOf(
         AssessmentProgressItem(
            stringProvider.kerangkaPerencanaanKuliahDanKarier,
            R.drawable.ic_home_video_open, //How should i provide it?
            R.drawable.ic_home_video_lock,
            R.drawable.ic_home_video_open,
            { AssessmentProgressItem.PROGRESS_STATUS_OPEN },
            true,
            0,
            {}
         ),
         AssessmentProgressItem(
            stringProvider.caraMengenaliDiri,
            R.drawable.ic_home_video_open,
            R.drawable.ic_home_video_lock,
            R.drawable.ic_home_video_open,
            { AssessmentProgressItem.PROGRESS_STATUS_OPEN },
            true,
            0,
            {}
         )
      )
   }
}
```

1. So, how should i provide drawable to my AssessmentListRepository? shall i providing Drawable class, or i just providing integer IDs?
2. Is Drawable an AndroidComponent?

Answer (score 0):

interesting question.
Hope I understood you correctly, because I don't understand why your repository needs drawables? What are going to do with those drawables? Return they back to VM?

Actually, I'm not sure that repository has to provide Drawable in general. And R.java is definitely Android specific class, so we can say that your Repository class depends on Android specific class.
I think better way do something like this:

1. Create independent class which will describe data you needs for your screen. Instead of drawables you can use enum/sealed classes to describe some data/states.
2. Repository will return that class (without drawables or similar resources)
3. ViewModel will ask data from repository and analyze that data.
4. ViewModel will change UI-related properties based on data from repository.
5. As View is observer on  UI-related properties of ViewModel, View will change UI-state automatically. Drawable and other resources should be used on this stage.

Cheers